# How to fill values in dictionary and pass them from view to POST

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, view, controller

So I have a dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<Section, List<EntryParameter>> sectionDict;
        //getting dictionary and pass it to model
    model.SectionDict=sectionDict;
```

I pass it from controller's GET method to View, where I want to fill values of each element in List (EntryParameter.Value)

The problem I have is that in post method i receive null instead of model.SectionDict

how to properly work on dictionaries or lists that are inside of my model?

Comment: please tell at least the framework you're using, otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: edited, .net mvc 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved this!
The problem was that to transport values through post method I have to use indexing. After building html, the name of the input cannot be coded in some way, that model does not understand. Using dictionary I was getting something like:

```
<input name="[1].EnterValue" class="form-control" 
    id="Parameter3" type="text" value="" data-val="true" data-val-required="!!!">
```

Instead, I've made model field:

```
List<EntryParameter> EntryParameterList
```

Where i keep filled values of elements from dictionary. 
Here's how I did this:

```
var listIndex = Model.EntryParametersList.IndexOf(Model.EntryParametersList.Where(o => o.Parameter.ID == Model.SectionDict.ToArray()[k].Value[i].Parameter.ID).First());
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.EntryParametersList[listIndex].EnterValue, new {(someAttributes)});
```

And the result is

```
<input name="EntryParametersList[1].EnterValue" class="form-control" 
    id="Parameter3" type="text" value="" data-val="true" data-val-required="!!!">
```

That solves the problem, everything goes to model.